# Setting up Nano 33 BLE as peripheral, problem with data types

Tags: types, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running a TensorFlowlite model on the Nano 33 BLE sense to recognise differently coloured objects. The TensorFlow code runs fine on its own and prints on the serial 1, 2, or 3 depending on which colour object is in front of the Nano.
I have managed to send temperature data from Nano to LightBlue app on my Android, as a test for the BLE code, which worked fine.

The problem I have is when I put the BLE code together with the TensorFlow code. As far as I can understand (I might be wrong) the problem is with the difference in data types between the BLEIntCharacteristic buttonCharacteristic and the value I am trying to send which is the CLASSES[maxIndex]. I have tried to use the atoi function to convert the const char* into int but my guess is that it is not right. I get no error messages when I run this but as soon as I try to scan an object with Nano it makes it crash.

I would much appreciate any advice on how to solve this!

```
// Arduino_TensorFlowLite - Version: 0.alpha.precompiled
#include <TensorFlowLite.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/kernels/all_ops_resolver.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/micro_error_reporter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/micro_interpreter.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h>
#include <tensorflow/lite/version.h>
#include <Arduino_APDS9960.h>
#include "model.h"

// global variables used for TensorFlow Lite (Micro)
tflite::MicroErrorReporter tflErrorReporter;

// pull in all the TFLM ops, you can remove this line and
// only pull in the TFLM ops you need, if would like to reduce
// the compiled size of the sketch.
tflite::ops::micro::AllOpsResolver tflOpsResolver;

const tflite::Model* tflModel = nullptr;
tflite::MicroInterpreter* tflInterpreter = nullptr;
TfLiteTensor* tflInputTensor = nullptr;
TfLiteTensor* tflOutputTensor = nullptr;

// Create a static memory buffer for TFLM, the size may need to
// be adjusted based on the model you are using
constexpr int tensorArenaSize = 8 * 1024;
byte tensorArena[tensorArenaSize];

// array to map gesture index to a name
const char* CLASSES[] = {
  "3", // u8"\U0001F34E", blue //
  "2", // u8"\U0001F34C", green//
  "1" // u8"\U0001F34A"  red//
};

#define NUM_CLASSES (sizeof(CLASSES) / sizeof(CLASSES[0]))

#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

BLEService ledService("19B10010-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // create service

// create button characteristic and allow remote device to get notifications
BLEIntCharacteristic buttonCharacteristic("19B10012-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {};

  // begin initialization
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  if (!APDS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing APDS9960 sensor.");
  }

  // get the TFL representation of the model byte array
  tflModel = tflite::GetModel(model);
  if (tflModel->version() != TFLITE_SCHEMA_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Model schema mismatch!");
    while (1);
  }

  // Create an interpreter to run the model
  tflInterpreter = new tflite::MicroInterpreter(tflModel, tflOpsResolver, tensorArena, tensorArenaSize, &tflErrorReporter);

  // Allocate memory for the model's input and output tensors
  tflInterpreter->AllocateTensors();

  // Get pointers for the model's input and output tensors
  tflInputTensor = tflInterpreter->input(0);
  tflOutputTensor = tflInterpreter->output(0);

  // set the local name peripheral advertises
  BLE.setLocalName("nano33");
  // set the UUID for the service this peripheral advertises:
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(ledService);

  // add the characteristics to the service
  ledService.addCharacteristic(buttonCharacteristic);

  // add the service
  BLE.addService(ledService);

  buttonCharacteristic.writeValue(0);

  // start advertising
  BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections...");
}

void loop() {
  //poll for BLE events
  BLE.poll();

  int r, g, b, p, c;
  float sum;
  int finIndex;
  int maxPercent = -1;
  int maxIndex = -1;


  // check if both color and proximity data sample is available
  while (!APDS.colorAvailable() || !APDS.proximityAvailable()) {}

  // read the color and proximity sensor
  APDS.readColor(r, g, b, c);
  p = APDS.readProximity();
  sum = r + g + b;

  // check if there's an object close and well illuminated enough
  if (p == 0 && c > 10 && sum > 0) {

    // normalize
    float redRatio = r / sum;
    float greenRatio = g / sum;
    float blueRatio = b / sum;

    // input sensor data to tensorflow
    tflInputTensor->data.f[0] = redRatio;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[1] = greenRatio;
    tflInputTensor->data.f[2] = blueRatio;

    // run inferencing
    TfLiteStatus invokeStatus = tflInterpreter->Invoke();
    if (invokeStatus != kTfLiteOk) {
      Serial.println("Invoke failed!");
      while (1);
      return;
    }

    // output results
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLASSES; i++) {
      int percent = (int(tflOutputTensor->data.f[i] * 100));
      if ( percent > maxPercent) {  //maxPercent is currently highest percentage from the i that the for loop has gone through
        maxPercent = percent;
        maxIndex = i;
      }
      (CLASSES[i]);
      (" ");
      (int(tflOutputTensor->data.f[i] * 100));
      ("%\n");
    }
          //read the current index
    buttonCharacteristic.writeValue(atoi(CLASSES[maxIndex]));
    Serial.println(CLASSES[maxIndex]);
    // wait for the object to be moved away
    while (!APDS.proximityAvailable() || (APDS.readProximity() == 0)) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like 'if (result == "1") buttonCharacteristic.writeValue(0x01);' and so on?

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, didn't get any different result.